# No post with 3 or 4 sticks

Tags: memory, motherboard

My specs:
Board;
MSI MAG B660 TOMAHAWK WIFI DDR4 (with most up to date BIOS (11/14 Release))
RAM
KF436C17BBK4/32
CPU
Core i5-12600k
I've tried everything. Resetting CMOC, holding the power button for 20 seconds, both XMP profiles. Also tried reseating the CPU, cleaning the DIMM slots, releasing some pressure from the CPU via the cooler mount. I have also tried lowering the RAM speeds to see if any speed would post, still no avail. I'm this close to ripping my hair out! I am out of warranty on the board, but I can return the new set of RAM if need be. No amount of research is bringing up anything that has worked, so far.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: how do you test `both XMP profiles` without a POST?

Comment: https://www.kingston.com/datasheets/KF436C17BBK4_32.pdf   Try comparing these settings with the manual settings in your BIOS.